# How to display User Profile Name Prefix (Mr. Mrs. Dr.) in SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, active-directory

The Column for User Profile Name Prefix (Mr. Mrs. Dr.) is not a default site column in SharePoint?

In VCard it is:
N:MyLastName;MyFirstName;MyMiddleName;MyPrefix (Mr.,  Mrs., Dr.);MySuffix (Sr., Jr.)

SharePoint has columns for First, Last, Middle, and Suffix - but no Prefix (Mr., Mrs., Dr.)

Comment: How are you trying to display it? Search, CSOM Social API? It depends on your approach.

Comment: Hi Matthew, we are a police agency and want to show the officers' rank (ideally without a custom column). The Prefix column in Outlook is perfect. The Suffix column exists, but not the Prefix. I may consider the Suffix.

Comment: Great, "show it" where? User Profile, Search Results, or? The answer will determine the approach.

Comment: Would rank be better served if mapped to the Job Title field?

Answer (score 1):

One approach, for example for "Prefix" would be to map the AD property personalTitle to a new User Profile Property that you create in the User Profile Service Application. If you are looking at Rank, it may be better to use a field like Job Title (which in AD is "title" that is already mapped to the User Profile Property JobTitle). Once you import your properties from AD the field will be populated.

Next you need to decide if you want to show it in search. If so you need to Managed the crawled property and then create a Display Template for that. This post walk through the details: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Currently, the RANK is entered in the Job Title, but now the officers want their Job title to display in Job Title and Rank as a separate column. ie: Sgt. John Doe, Homicide Investigator. --> (Rank. First Last, Job Title). I will look into the above and post what works. Cheers!

Comment: Great, that is the detail I was looking for, your approach makes sense. Many ways to achieve that. Let me know if you get stuck.